# Passing array (of objects) from popup.js to content.js in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I have an array that is created and modified upon user input in my popup.js file, and I want to be able to send it to my content.js script upon the click of a button (in popup.html). Currently, chrome.runtime.sendMessage seems to only let me pass string (or JSON?) type messages to content.js, so I am having a hard time thinking of a solution to getting this array of objects as well as a message (something like 'start_search') over to content.js for execution.

For reference here is the array of objects:

```
var searchList = [];
```

Here is the function that constructs it (triggered upon user submission):

```
function addWord(userWord, userColor){ //append new word 
    var wordAndColorPair = {
        word: userWord,
        color: userColor,
        id: placementId.toString() //keep it as a string so it can be used for highlighted word's class
    }
    searchList.push(wordAndColorPair); //pushing the new object with user inputs to array
}
```

Below is my attempt at using JSON.stringify:

```
popup.js:
    .
    .
    var jsonSearchList = JSON.stringify(searchList);
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, jsonSearchList);


content.js:
    alert(request.message); //alerts "undefined"....
```

Comment: I have tried using JSON.stringify to send the array of objects as a string, but it doesnt work, and I am also not able to attach a message as well

Comment: Which part of `JSON.stringify` are you having the problem with? Can you post any relevant code that deals with the messaging on both sides?

Comment: is JSON.stringify the only solution?

Comment: The message passing API uses serialized JSON as the data interchange format. Simply use `JSON.stringify` to serialize data into the JSON string and, at the other end, use `JSON.parse` to deserialize the JSON string back.

Comment: Is there some way to pass this information, using a different method? (other than sendMessage?)

Comment: I recommend reading the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) on chrome extension message passing which have many examples of messaging between [all environments](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) of the extension. As for the another way to pass that information, that is the easiest and the most reliable way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of what I said in the comments regarding sending a message from the `popup.js` to the `content.js`:

**Popup.html:**

```
<body>
    <button id="test">Send data</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

**Popup.js:**

```
var searchList=[{test1:1},{test2:2}];
var jsonSearchList = JSON.stringify(searchList);

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            data: jsonSearchList
        });
    });
});
```

**Content.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.data !== undefined) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(msg.data));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, as it cleared several things up. However, after using JSON.parse() on the request.data -> the result is [object Object, object Object etc..] ?

Comment: That happens since you are logging a string representation of an object, you can still parse it and store it in a variable which you can then use as required.